# Trouble implementing object creation in Java

Tags: java, object

The project I'm working on is a bank interface with a single `PatronList` object, which itself contains `BankPatron` objects containing `BankAccount` objects. The issue I'm facing is that I can't seem to get create any new objects. The main method only uses a single `PatronList` object, but any `BankPatron` or `BankAccount` objects I try to create aren't but will still output that they have for some reason. In my program all objects are already premade and set as equal to null. There's a lot of code to this and I'm not sure what might be necessary so I'm sorry if I post too much here.

So the interface menu starts with this:

List Patrons

Add New Patron

Remove Patron

Patron specific questions

Quit

If you select 'd' then you get transferred to a second menu that looks like this:

Add new account

Close account

Get Paid

Apply interest to accounts

Make deposit

Make withdraw

Return Main Menu

To add list patrons, the code is as follows in the main method:

```
if(option.equals("a"))
{
    if(((pList.getBankPatron(0)==null)&&(pList.getBankPatron(1)==null)&&(pList.getBankPatron(2)==null)&&(pList.getBankPatron(3)==null)&&(pList.getBankPatron(4)==null)))
    {
        System.out.println("None.");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i =0; i<=4;i++)
        {
            if( pList.getBankPatron(i)!=null)
            {
                BankPatron u = pList.getBankPatron(i);
                pList.patronInfo(u);}
            }
        }
    }
```

To add patrons, it is:

```
if(option.equals("b"))
{
    System.out.println("What is the patron's first name?");
    String fname = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Last name?");
    String lname = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Their salary?");
    double salary = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Their cash on hand?");
    double cash = scan.nextDouble();
    if(pList.addPatron(fname, lname, salary, cash))
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the bank.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Bank line is full, sorry.");
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the `BankPatron` class:

```
public class PatronList {

    private BankPatron patronOne;
    private BankPatron patronTwo;
    private BankPatron patronThree;
    private BankPatron patronFour;
    private BankPatron patronFive;

    public PatronList()
    {
        patronOne =null;
        patronTwo =null;
        patronThree =null;
        patronFour =null;
        patronFive =null;
    }
    public boolean addPatron(BankPatron e)
    {
        boolean success =false;
        if(patronOne==null)
        {
            patronOne = e;
            success =true;
        }
        else if(patronTwo==null)
        {
            patronTwo = e;
            success =true;
        }
        else if(patronThree==null)
        {
            patronThree = e;
            success =true;
        }
        else if(patronFour==null)
        {
            patronFour = e;
            success =true;
        }
        else if(patronFive==null)
        {
            patronFive = e;
            success =true;
        }
        return success;
    }
    public boolean addPatron(String fname, String lname, double pay, double cash)
    {
        BankPatron b = new BankPatron(fname, lname,pay,cash);
        return this.addPatron(b);
    }
    public BankPatron getBankPatron(int i)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
        case 0: return patronOne; 
        case 1: return patronTwo; 
        case 2: return patronThree; 
        case 3: return patronFour; 
        case 4: return patronFive;
        default: return null; 
        }

    }
    public BankPatron getBankPatron(String name)
    {
        if(patronOne!=null)
        {
            if(name.equals(patronOne.getName()))
            {   
                return patronOne;
            }
            else
            return null;
        }
        if(patronTwo!=null)
        {
            if(name.equals(patronTwo.getName()))
            {   
                return patronTwo;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        if(patronThree!=null)
        {
            if(name.equals(patronThree.getName()))
            {   
                return patronThree;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        if(patronFour!=null)
        {
            if(name.equals(patronFour.getName()))
            {   
                return patronFour;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        if(patronFive!=null)
        {
            if(name.equals(patronFive.getName()))
            {   
                return patronFive;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
        return null;
    }
    public boolean removePatron(BankPatron e)
    {
        boolean success=true;
        if(e==patronOne)
        {
            patronOne=null;
        }
        else if(e==patronTwo)
        {
            patronTwo=null;
        }
        else if(e==patronThree)
        {
            patronThree=null;
        }
        else if(e==patronFour)
        {
            patronFour=null;
        }
        else if(e==patronFive)
        {
            patronFive=null;
        }
        else
        {
            success=false;
        }
        return success;
    }
    public String patronInfo(BankPatron a)
    {
        String s = a.toString();
        return s;
    }



}
```

Code for Bank Patron class:

```
public class BankPatron {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double salary;
    private double cashOnHand;
    private BankAccount accountOne;
    private BankAccount accountTwo;

    public BankPatron()
    {
        firstName = "John";
        lastName = "Doe";
        salary = 50000.00;
        cashOnHand = 2300.00;
        accountOne = null;
        accountTwo=null;
    }
    public BankPatron(String fname, String lname, double pay, double cash)
    {
        firstName= fname;
        lastName=lname;
        salary=pay;
        cashOnHand= cash;
        accountOne = null;
        accountTwo=null;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
    public double getCashOnHand()
    {
        return cashOnHand;
    }

    public void payCheck()
    {
        double paycheck = salary / 26;
        cashOnHand+= paycheck;
    }
    public BankAccount getBankAccount(int i)
    {
        if(i !=1 ||i!=2)
        {
            return null;

        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
            return accountOne;
        }
        else
        return accountTwo;
    }
    public boolean deposit(int account, double depo)
    {
        if(account==1 && accountOne != null)
        {
            if(cashOnHand>=depo)
            {
                cashOnHand-=depo;
                accountOne.deposit(depo);
                return true;
            }
            else
            return false;
        }
        if(account==2 && accountTwo != null)
        {
            if(cashOnHand>=depo)
            {
                cashOnHand-=depo;
                accountTwo.deposit(depo);
                return true;
            }
            else
            return false;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
    public boolean withdraw(int account, double wdraw)
    {
        if(account==1 && accountOne != null)
        {
            if(accountOne.withdraw(wdraw)== true)
            {
                cashOnHand+=wdraw;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(account==2 && accountTwo != null)
        {
            if(accountTwo.withdraw(wdraw)== true)
            {
                cashOnHand+=wdraw;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
    public boolean addAccount(double rate, AccountType type)
    {
        boolean success=true;
        if(accountOne==null)
        {
            accountOne = new BankAccount(firstName, lastName, rate, type);      
        }
        else if(accountTwo==null)
        {
            accountTwo = new BankAccount(firstName, lastName, rate, type);      
        }
        else
        {
            success=false;
        }
        return success;
    }
    public boolean removeAccount(int i)
    {
        if(i==1 && accountOne!=null)
        {
            accountOne=null;
            return true;
        }
        if(i==2 && accountTwo!=null)
        {
            accountTwo=null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String output=this.getName();
        if(accountOne != null)
        {
            output+= accountOne.getType()+ " " + accountOne.getAccountNum() + " Balance: " + accountOne.checkBalance()+" Interest Rate: "+ accountOne.getRate();
        }
        if(accountTwo != null)
        {
            output+= " "+ accountTwo.getType()+ " " + accountTwo.getAccountNum() + " Balance: " + accountTwo.checkBalance()+" Interest Rate: "+ accountTwo.getRate();
        }
        return output;
    }


}
```

Code for `BankAccount` class:

```
public class BankAccount
{    
    private int accountNumber;
    private double balance;
    private double interestRate;
    private String holderFirstName;
    private String holderLastName;
    private AccountType type;

    private static int nextAccountNum = 1001;

    public BankAccount()
    {
        accountNumber = getNextAccountNum();
        balance = 0.0;
        interestRate = 0.0;
        holderFirstName = "";
        holderLastName = "";
        type = AccountType.Checking;
    }

    public BankAccount(String first, String last, double rate, AccountType at)
    {
        accountNumber = getNextAccountNum();
        balance = 0.0;
        interestRate = rate;
        holderFirstName = first;
        holderLastName = last;
        type = at;
    }

    private int getNextAccountNum()
    {
        return nextAccountNum++;
    }

    public int getAccountNum()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public double checkBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public boolean withdraw(double amount)
    {
        boolean success = true;
        if((balance - amount) >= 0.0) // Only able to withdraw if there is actually enough money.
        {
            balance -= amount;
        }
        else
        {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }

    public double getRate()
    {
        return interestRate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate)
    {
        interestRate = rate;
    }

    public void applyInterest()
    {
        balance += (balance * (interestRate / 100));
    }

    public String getHolderFullName()
    {
        return holderFirstName + " " + holderLastName;
    }

    public AccountType getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. How do you know they are not being created? In what way do they output that they have?

Comment: @maharvey67 After you enter the information needed to create a patron, you get the output "Welcome to the bank". You then return to the main menu. If you try to add an account to that patron by going to the patron specific menu, then you are asked for the full name of the patron you are trying to access. I keep getting the output for when the name inputted is not associated with a patron. Also, if I try to list the patrons, I don't outright get the output for when there are no patrons added to the list, for some reason I just get no output at all.

Comment: What is the problem? Did you get any exception?

Comment: @TiyebM No exceptions, no. The way my code is set up, it's basically impossible for that to happen. Instead, I just can't access new BankPatron objects I create since my program is unable to find a patron of the name I just called them. So it's as though they don't even exist

Comment: "...it's **as though** they don't exist...": maybe they _do_ exist but the  "patron specific" menu is not finding them.  Have you debugged that code?

Comment: Try adding temporary print statements to areas in the code where you're not sure what's going on. For example, in getBankPatron(String name), you could print the value of the name argument, and then print the name of each patron you're comparing to, to visually inspect what it is doing.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I've looked it over but can't seem to find anything wrong with it. The same issue happens when I try to list patrons which has nothing to do with the patron specific menu.

Comment: Your code to list the patrons doesn't ever actually **ouput** anything.  You get the patron info, but never actually display it!

Comment: @KevinAnderson Are you sure? I use the patronInfo() method for the patron list in the else body for the the listing option don't I?

Comment: OK, you used `patronInfo()`: how do you suppose that would have gotten anything printed?  `patronInfo()` itself doesn't print anything, it just _returns_ a `String` to whatever called it.  `patronInfo()` calls the `toString()` method on `Patron`, but `toString()` doesn't print anything, it just _returns_ a `String` to whatever called _it_ (`patronInfo()`, in this case).  So where was any printing done?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Oh, I see now! Well that solves one of my issues, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how this could be useful to anyone else, but I figured out why I wasn't able to retrieve any created BankAccount objects. The issue was the method below and was a simple logic error; I had OR in the first if statement instead of AND. Kevin's comments show why I was having trouble with creating the BankPatron objects as well.

```html
public BankAccount getBankAccount(int i)
 {
  if(i !=1 || i!=2)
  {
   return null;
   
  }
  else if(i == 1)
  {
   return accountOne;
  }
  else
  return accountTwo;
```